# Interactive elements (anchor tag) not getting focus in swipe in ipad with voiceover

Tags: web, ipad, safari, accessibility, voiceover

For my website developed in Reactjs, I am using a link with anchor element. In ipad with voiceover it is not getting focus for those links in right or left swipe but have given tabIndex="0".Working fine in other tabs and desktop browsers(on pressing tab in keyboard).

Comment: You will need to provide us with an example that replicates the problem, could you set a fiddle up? There could be loads of reasons, invalid `href`, javascript intercepting and interfering etc. etc. it is impossible for us to help from the information provided I am afraid. Please add a fiddle that has the same problem so we can help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example